# Configure highlighted part in the elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

**Main question**
The user is looking for a name and enters the part of the it, let's say `au`, and the document with the text `paul` is found.
I would like to have the doc highlighted like `p<em>au</em>l`.
How can I achieve it if I have a complex search query (combination of match, prefix, wildcard to rule relevance)?

**Sub question**
When do highlight settings from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#highlighting-settings) for `type`, `boundary_scanner` and `boundary_chars` come into play? As per my tests described below, these settings don't change highlighted part.

**Try 1: Wildcard query with default analyzer**

```
PUT myindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
POST myindex/_doc/1
{
    "name": "paul"
}
```

```
GET myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {"name": "*au*"}
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": { 
            "name": {}
        },
        "type": "fvh",
        "boundary_scanner": "chars",
        "boundary_chars": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,!? \t\n"
    }
}
```

This kind of search returns highlight `<em>paul</em>` but I need to get `p<em>au</em>l`.

**Try 2: Match query with NGRAM analyzer**
This one works as described in SO question: [Highlighting part of word in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310610/highlighting-part-of-word-in-elasticsearch)

```
PUT myindexngram
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "max_gram": "3",
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "index_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                },
                "search_term_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "index_ngram_analyzer",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
POST myindexngram/_doc/1
{
    "name": "paul"
}
```

```
GET myindexngram/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"name": "au"}
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": { 
            "name": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This highlights `p<em>au</em>l` as desired but:

1. Highlighting depends on the query type, so combining `match` and `wildcard` will again result in `<em>paul</em>`.
2. Highlighting is not affected at all on `type`, `boundary_scanner` and `boundary_chars` settings.

Elastic version 7.13.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Elasticsearch team:

> A highlighter works on terms, so only full terms can be highlighted - whatever are the terms in your index. In your second example, `au` could be highlighted, because it it a term in the index, which is not the case for your first example.
> There is also an option to define your own `highlight_query` that could be different from the main `query`, but this could lead to unpredictable highlights.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configure-highlighted-part/295164